# Wordpress Menu does not change for responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

i made this wordpress installation and built up the page so far: 
http://latin-festival.viv-werbeagentur.de/

Now i am trying to get a mobile menu into this. Every Mobile Menu Plugin I install in Wordpress does not change ANYTHING in the navigation menu. Nothing changes. Anyone got some idea how i can make this menu go responsive?

Greetings

Comment: Try to check the plugin's documentation.

Comment: well i think it´s obvious to check the documentation before asking here. But i have the feeling that somehow the plugins have no access to my menu. i mean really nothing happens. the computer-version does not hide, no button for the mobile menu appears, nothing.

Comment: please provide your plugin url

Comment: i got this: http://magnigenie.com/wp-responsive-menu-mobile-menu-plugin-wordpress/ and this: http://peterfeatherstone.com/wordpress/responsive-menu/

Comment: check your WPR Menu setting in wp-admin. it's work for me.

Comment: http://latin-festival.viv-werbeagentur.de/wp-content/themes/latin-festival/wpm_1.png , http://latin-festival.viv-werbeagentur.de/wp-content/themes/latin-festival/wpm_2.png ... does not work, and yeah i tried chosing a logo for the menu :P

Comment: You didn't specify the "Elements to hide in mobile", try `#menu-hauptmenue`

Comment: Also you have two menus with the same links and one of them hidden behind the `header-container` div, why?

Comment: in this plugin Menu Open Direction=> "right" and "left" not working on proper way but Menu Open Direction=> "top" is working

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu   /https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-select-menu/  try these plugins

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-select-menu/ this one is the only one that appears on my page after installing... but if i chose a page in the menu nothing happens. i just stay on the page i am.